# Deploying on VPS with git and capistrano (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx, capistrano, rbenv

Good evening,
i have a VPS in which i set up git and following all the environment (nginx, unicorn, postgresql, rbenv, capistrano, rails, unicorn, nodejs).

Everything seems working fine, but I encounter some issues when it comes to

```
cap deploy:cold
```

After some changes i have git and the app i want to publish on the same VPS, but i can't get it working since it's asking for different passwords which are basicly useless, i understood the issue, i'm calling the repository like using one of github and seems wrong but i don't know what to use to make it to deploy...

**deploy.rb**

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

load "config/recipes/base"
load "config/recipes/nginx"
load "config/recipes/unicorn"
load "config/recipes/postgresql"
load "config/recipes/nodejs"
load "config/recipes/rbenv"
load "config/recipes/check"

server "192.192.192.192", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :user, "deployer"
set :application, "phs"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "#{user}@#{server}:/home/deployer/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

thank you for the help, you were essential in all the building of my first app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i added

```
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
```

on the ddeploy.rb file and i just made great attention to all kind of errors that were put in terminal, googling, trying and making it work eventually i made it work, sadly i can't remember the exact procedures

Answer (score 0):

You are deploying using the VPS's local git repo?  Why not deploy from github with:

```
set :repository, git@github.com:repo_directory/#{application}.git
```

?

Comment: Because i just want to use a personal repo for this, the problem is around line 20 when i should connect to my repo on its own localhost he makes an ssh which i don t want, i wonder what else may i do to achieve this correctly

Comment: Have you tried using https instead with localhost or the server IP as the host? (just a theory)